# Why is the gettimeofday timezone wrong?

Tags: timezone, posix, ubuntu-16.04

Both ftime and gettimeofday are returning 0 for the current timezone in Ubuntu 16. The timezone is set correctly in the date and time settings provided by Ubuntu. There is no TZ env variable set.

I don't want to just "fix" it because this is production software used in many different contexts. So I just want a reliable way of programmatically getting the timezone (and preferably the current DST offset as well).

My attempts so far:

```
#if 0
timeb tbTime;
ftime(&tbTime);
int CurTz = -tbTime.timezone;
#else
struct timeval tv;
struct timezone tz;
int r = gettimeofday(&tv, &tz);
if (r)
    return NO_ZONE;

int CurTz = tz.tz_minuteswest;
#endif
```

The 'date' command is working:

```
matthew@mallen-ubuntu:~$ date +%Z
AEDT
matthew@mallen-ubuntu:~$ date +%z
+1100
```

I could just spawn a process to call "date", but that seems very heavy handed when some API calls are available.

Comment: That works correctly for me (no TZ env defined too). Tested on OSX.

Comment: Probably because different systems have different settings. That codes works fine on Windows for instance. And maybe my Ubuntu is busted somehow? But I need to have it work on similar "busted" systems out in the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On GNU/Linux, the second argument of `gettimeofday` is quite useless and should always be `NULL`.  The [manual page for `gettimeofday`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html) says this:

> The use of the timezone structure is obsolete; the tz argument should normally be specified as NULL.

Even on non-Linux systems, the `tz_dsttime` has useless semantics (e.g., it reports that India uses DST because it did so for a brief period about seventy years ago).

If you need to obtain the time zone for the current time, you need to use `localtime` or `localtime_r` and examine the broken-down time structure it produces (and not global variables such as `daylight`).  The `struct tm` members you are probably interested are `tm_isdst`, `tm_gmtoff`, and perhaps `tm_zone`.  The latter two are glibc extensions.

Comment: Ok so I still can't get what I want from localtime. Is there an API to get the information that the "date" command returns?

Comment: You can use `localtime` or `localtime_r`. I have clarified my answer.